# Best performance? treat data in DB and get result directly OR get result and then work on it?

Tags: php, performance, jakarta-ee, symfony1

I have a small question about performance during dev (web especially) :

Is it better to :

1. perform operations **directly** on the DB and retreive a **"ready" result**

   OR
2. retreive the data from the DB and **then** do the operations?

Comment: The only valid answers to this question are "it depends" and "try it and measure".

Comment: Thanks MAT. but are there any recommendations or even tricks to get it  or even to have an idea?

Comment: No general thing, it all depends on how much data is at stake, how it's represented/indexed in the db, and what type of processing needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mat is right (see comments): there is no general answer to that. It depends on the structure of your data, on the queries you want to run and on your database system.

Nevertheless I would say, in most traditional cases it is better to join, filter, group, cumulate and sort your data directly in the DB - just because your DB is built to perform exactly this kind of tasks. If your data structure and indexes are built up right, it will be hard to write code beating the database in terms of performance on this actions.

Indeed, there are complex queries where it is better to split it up and do some work in your code. But unless you have more than 10 tables involved or big sub queries, you should not think about this to much.